# To show a series is summable

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive reals such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+x_n)<\infty.$$ Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n<\infty?$

(From given condition, it follows that $x_n\to 0.$ But I can not proceed further.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $t \to 0^+$, we see $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} = 1.$$ This can be proven by l'Hopital's or Taylor expansion. In particular, this implies that there is $\delta > 0$ such that $$t \in (0,\delta) \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, \frac 1 2 \le \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} \le \frac 3 2 \,\,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, \frac t 2 \le \ln(1+t) \le \frac{3t}{2}, $$ and the last bound clearly holds for $t = 0$ as well. As you pointed out, if $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \ln(1+x_n) < \infty$$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$. Thus there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \ge N$ yields $x_n \in [0,\delta)$ whereupon $$\frac{x_n}{2} \le \ln(1+x_n) \le \frac{3x_n}2.$$ Since this holds for all $n \ge N$, we see $$\frac 1 2\sum^\infty_{n=N} x_n \le \sum^\infty_{n=N} \ln(1+x_n) \le \frac 3 2 \sum^\infty_{n=N} x_n.$$ This is sufficient to conclude that for and positive sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$, the sums $\sum \ln(1+x_n)$ and $\sum x_n$ either both converge or both diverge.

Comment: Just want to humbly add that $\log(1+x)\leq x$ follows everywhere

Answer (score 1):

My attempt.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+x_n)<\infty \Rightarrow \log(1+x_n)$ is a zero sequence $\Rightarrow x_n$ is a zero sequence $\Rightarrow$

$ \Rightarrow  x_n<1$ for all but finitely many $n $

It can be shown that $ \frac{x}{2} \leq \ln(1+x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Hence, for all but finitely many $n$, $\log(1+x_n) \geq \frac12 \cdot x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges by comparison.

Comment: I think $x/2 \leq \log(1+x) \forall x\in[0,1]$ is not true. Can you please justify!

Comment: $f(x)=ln(1+x)-x/2$, and $f'(x)=(1-x)/2(x+1)>0$ so $f$ it is increasing in interval $\forall x\in[0,1]$